# Assembly and c-language - a comparison of filesizes

Tags: c, assembly

I made two hello-world programs - one in x86 assembly using the debugger in CMD, another in c-language.

As the assembly-language gives very exact instructions to the CPU its not surprising that the executable file occupy less bytes in memory than the executable c-file. But I was surprised that the difference is really huge: out put below:

```
hello world in x86 assembly: 30 bytes

hello world in c-language: 102 kb
```

That is - the c-program is 3400 times the assembly program.

I first thought that it could be explained by including headerfiles as in this context **stdio.h** but when compiling without it the file-size was only reduced to 95KB.

SO - my question is - what is that makes the c-file much much heavier in bytes than the assembly file? Could it be certain dll-files that this executable is dependent of?

**the x86 assembly code:**

```
jmp 115
db 'Hello world!$'
-a 115 
mov ah, 09
mov dx, 102
int 21
int 20
```

**the c-code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello world!");
}
```

*The c-program is compiled with MinGW, using default option*

Comment: You haven't specified which compiler and compiler options you're using.

Comment: Using a DLL does not affect the size of your executable. That is why it's called **DLL** (dynamically linked library) - a piece of code which is **not statically** linked to the executable.

Comment: Just as a test I did `gcc -Os -o hellosmall hellosmall.c && strip hellosmall` (with the C code in your question), and got an executable that was 4622 bytes (x86-64, cygwin).

Comment: Instead of using `printf` you can use `write` and you'll notice that it will become MUCH smaller. Not as muc as an assembly program, but way closer.

Comment: Your program written in C contains all the runtime and startup code required for C. e.g. it might up stdin/stdout/stderr, contains machinery for running atexit() handlers when the program exits, and so on. Depending on compiler flags, the executable might contain debugging information, instructions to link to the C runtime, code to zero out  any data segment ...

Comment: I just tried to reduce the sizem and it doesn't get lower then 17.920 bytes. No matter if I use printf or not.

Comment: You should try Hello World in Ada.  Last time I did that it compiled to just over 1 MiB!

Comment: @Devolus Even if you don't include any headers, there's still the extra stuff I mentioned above.

Comment: @nos, I know that. I just wanted to see how low it can get. Last time I did that it got to around 4kb, but this was some years ago. Seems that there is more included now, or maybe MingW adds additional stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This overhead is likely caused by the compiler's default runtime-library being included, since you're using it to call `printf()`. Note that `printf()` is **way** more capable a function than [the DOS interrupt](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-9.html) you're calling. All that capability of course means it consists of way more code. You could try switching `printf()` to `puts()`.

I'm not saying that `printf()` alone is 102 KB, it probably is far from that, but you also get the entire library, it's support code (init/de-init, exit-handlers, and so on) and not just that one function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really simple:

Compiler overhead.

Also you use syscalls, and printf is a function call.